# Infura node seems to crash when tryining to deploy contract

Tags: go-ethereum, infura, golang

I am trying to deploy a contract and run some tests on the functions within it.

Here is what my code currently looks like:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "crypto/rand"
    "encoding/hex"
    "flag"
    "math/big"
    "strings"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"

    "github.com/HyperspaceApp/ed25519"
    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/abi/bind"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common/hexutil"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient"
    solidityEd25519 "github.com/javgh/ed25519-solidity/contract"
)

var myenv map[string]string

const envLoc = ".env"

func loadEnv() {
    var err error
    if myenv, err = godotenv.Read(envLoc); err != nil {
        log.Printf("could not load env from %s: %v", envLoc, err)
    }
}

func toBigEndian(littleEndian []byte) []byte {
    bigEndian := make([]byte, len(littleEndian))
    for i := range littleEndian {
        bigEndian[i] = littleEndian[len(littleEndian)-1-i]
    }
    return bigEndian
}

func main() {

    var n = flag.Int("n", 3, "number of test cases to generate")
    flag.Parse()

    loadEnv()

    ctx := context.Background()

    // client, err := ethclient.Dial(os.Getenv("KOVAN"))
    client, err := ethclient.Dial("https://kovan.infura.io/v3/<!--SNIP-->")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("could not connect to Ethereum gateway: %v\n", err)
    }
    defer client.Close()


    account := common.HexToAddress("0x2D76d8729F9Cfa5bC3CEba8a504400FE30bb53D2")
    balance, err := client.BalanceAt(ctx, account, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(balance)


    auth, _ := bind.NewTransactor(strings.NewReader("keystore/UTC--2019-12-19T11-17-59.397909000Z--2d76d8729f9cfa5bc3ceba8a504400fe30bb53d2"), "Poppop12!")
    // auth := bind.NewKeyedTransactor(privateKey)
    auth.GasLimit = uint64(100000000)

    // address, _, instance, err := solidityEd25519.DeployEd25519(auth, client)
    address, tx, instance, err := solidityEd25519.DeployEd25519(auth, client)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Waiting for contract to be deployed.
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println(address.Hex()) // 0x147B8eb97fD247D06C4006D269c90C1908Fb5D54
    fmt.Println(tx.GasPrice())
    fmt.Println(tx.Hash().Hex())

    for i := 0; i < *n; i++ {
        // Create random keypair and compare results from Go and Solidity
        adaptor, adaptorPoint, err := ed25519.GenerateAdaptor(rand.Reader)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        publicKey, privateKey, err := ed25519.GenerateKey(rand.Reader)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        fmt.Println(publicKey)
        fmt.Println(privateKey)

        adaptorBigInt := new(big.Int).SetBytes(toBigEndian(adaptor[:]))
        adaptorPointBytes := toBigEndian(adaptorPoint[:])
        adaptorPointBytes[0] &= 127 // clear sign bit
        adaptorPointBigInt := new(big.Int).SetBytes(adaptorPointBytes)

        _, adaptorPointSolidity, err := instance.ScalarMultBase(nil, adaptorBigInt)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        var estimateScalarMultBase []byte
        estimateScalarMultBase = append(estimateScalarMultBase, hexutil.MustDecode("0xc4f4912b")...) // scalarMultBase
        estimateScalarMultBase = append(estimateScalarMultBase, common.LeftPadBytes(adaptorBigInt.Bytes(), 32)...)

        gasEstimateestimateScalarMultBase, err := client.EstimateGas(context.Background(), ethereum.CallMsg{
            To:   &address,
            Data: estimateScalarMultBase,
        })
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }



        wasSuccessful := adaptorPointBigInt.Cmp(adaptorPointSolidity) == 0
        if wasSuccessful {
            fmt.Printf("\nTest successful:\n")
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("\nTest failed:\n")
        }
        fmt.Printf("  Adaptor (little endian)                   : %s\n",
            hex.EncodeToString(adaptor[:]))
        fmt.Printf("  Adaptor (big int, hex)                    : %s\n",
            adaptorBigInt.Text(16))
        fmt.Printf("  Adaptor (big int, decimal)                : %s\n",
            adaptorBigInt.Text(10))
        fmt.Printf("\n")
        fmt.Printf("  Adaptor point (big int, decimal, Go)      : %s\n",
            adaptorPointBigInt.Text(10))
        fmt.Printf("  Adaptor point (big int, decimal, Solidity): %s\n",
            adaptorPointSolidity.Text(10))
        fmt.Printf("\n")
        fmt.Printf("  Gas estimate for Scalar Multiplication: %d\n", gasEstimateestimateScalarMultBase)
        if !wasSuccessful {
            log.Fatal("last test failed")
        }
    }
}
```

Unforunately , I get this error:

```
11000000000000000000
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x38 pc=0x455fe00]

goroutine 1 [running]:
```

I would appreciate any pointers on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
auth, _ := bind.NewTransactor(strings.NewReader("keystore/UTC--2019-12-19T11-17-59.397909000Z--2d76d8729f9cfa5bc3ceba8a504400fe30bb53d2"), "Poppop12!")
```

Here `_auth` is probably `nil`.  Try logging `_auth` after this line.

Also, `strings.NewReader("...")` creates reader that reads from the string passed as the argument,not from the file whose name is passed.  Should probably be `os.Open("...")`.

Comment: You are right is is nil,do you know why?

Comment: Maybe its because i try to convert keystore (string) into a string reader? the documentation says NewTransactor must take a reader of keystore

Comment: Just try printing the second returned value (`_` in your case).

Comment: not sure how to print the `_` as the compiler throws an error saying i cant use it as a value

Comment: Just give it different name (e.g. `err`) and then print.

Comment: I figure it out.. I wasnt parsing the key properly. it was passing the file name and not the contents i.e a json blob. copied and pasted and it works now!

Comment: if you edit your answer to show to do that i am happy to accept it as you helped debug

Comment: Edited the answer